# Import JSON Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am trying to import a JSON array and convert it to an NSArray for a UITableView, but can't work out how to grab the data.

My JSON is formatted as so when I use curl:

```
[{"location_name":"??"},{"location_name":"105"},{"location_name":"106"},{"location_name":"106A"},{"location_name":"106b"},{"location_name":"107"},{"location_name":"108"},{"location_name":"109"},{"location_name":"110"},{"location_name":"111"},{"location_name":"112"},{"location_name":"113"},{"location_name":"114"}]
```

My xCode code is as follows:

```
// Parse out the JSON data

NSError *jsonError;

NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];

NSString* location_name = [json objectForKey:@"location_name"];

NSLog(@"Location Name: %@", location_name);
```

But in my console output I only get: "Location Name: (null)"

Comment: Have you tested the `jsonError` variable? That might give you some hints as to what is going on.

Comment: First, the JSON you have supplied is an array of objects, so using [json objectForKey:@"location_name"] will not produce anything.

If you log out json what does it produce?

Comment: Are you sure you have given all the details here? The code you have should crash and not print `Location Name: (null)`

Comment: Go to json.org and spend the 5 minutes it takes to learn JSON syntax.  What you have is an array of "objects" (dictionaries), not a single object/dictionary.  And as @68cherries says, you should print the error parm, since it appears that the JSON did not convert at all.

Comment: Ok, wow, thanks, there are so many answers so quickly! I will work through, these make a lot of sense and I am sure they will fix it, thanks for your help, i'll report back with what works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're json structure is an Array containing several object. When you parse it using the NSJSONSerialization, you get an NSArray back, not a NSDictionnary.
So you probably need of a for loop!

`NSError *jsonError;`

`NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];`

`for(NSDictionnary * item in json)`

`{`

`NSString* location_name = [item objectForKey:@"location_name"];`

`NSLog(@"Location Name: %@", location_name);`

`}`

Answer (score 2):

Your root json object is not a dictionary but an array:

```
[{"location_name":"??"},{"location_name":"105"},{"location_name":"106"},{"location_name":"106A"},{"location_name":"106b"},{"location_name":"107"},{"location_name":"108"},{"location_name":"109"},{"location_name":"110"},{"location_name":"111"},{"location_name":"112"},{"location_name":"113"},{"location_name":"114"}]
```

As a result, here is how you can display its content:

```
NSError *e = nil;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

if (!jsonArray) {
  NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", e);
} else {
   for(NSDictionary *item in jsonArray) {
      NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
   }
}
```

Comment: Using this I am getting an error: "{NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}" I have tried allowing fragments but then get "{NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}", Any ideas? Just googling up on it now.

Comment: *Its working! My PHP file had this line: print_r($result); Which must have been interfering, removed that and data is downloaded. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON contains an array of dictionaries, thus do:

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
                                                     options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                                       error:&jsonError];
```

Then you can loop through the array (or pick the one according to the indexPath of your tableView) to get a single location.

Answer (score 0):

If you literally just want to create an array of `location_name`'s then you should change `objectForKey:` to `valueForKey:`, which will return you the array you want.

```
NSArray *locationNames = [json valueForKey:@"location_name"];
```

The reason this works is because you have an array of dictionaries. If you call `valueForKey:` on an array it will collect the result of calling `valueForKey:` on each of it's elements